# Why does splitting TCP message on client side doesn't work?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, client-server

I've written a Client-Server application using C#.

The client asynchronously sends a message with a 4-byte header defining the message size, and the server waits for the **entire** message (it knows the size) and then raises a `DataReceived` event. This all works fine when I send and receive the data asynchronously.

At some point I wanted to simulate a bad connection, in which 2 segments were sent one after the other using `Send()` and not `BeginSend()`

```
  public void SendSyncString(string str, Commands cmd)
    {

        BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(new MemoryStream());
        bw.Write((int)cmd);
        bw.Write((int)str.Length);
        bw.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str));
        bw.Close();
        byte[] data = ((MemoryStream)(bw.BaseStream)).ToArray();
        bw.BaseStream.Dispose();
        SendSync(data,1);

    }

    public void SendSync(byte[] data,int delay)
    {
        //create |dataLength|data| segment
        byte[] dataWithHeader = Combine(BitConverter.GetBytes(data.Length), data);
        //send first block of data, delay, and then send the rest
        socket.Send(dataWithHeader, 0, 4, SocketFlags.None);
        Thread.Sleep(delay*1000);
        socket.Send(dataWithHeader, 5, dataWithHeader.Length - 5, SocketFlags.None);
    }
```

This **doesn't** work. I do wish to understand why though.
If I a TCP is simply a stream of bytes, and there's no way to know when each segment will arrive, 
why can't I split it to segments as I wish and simply send them like I did above (Assuming the first 4 bytes were sent fully)?

Thanks for the insights.

Comment: "This obviously doesn't work" is very pure explanation of problem you are facing... Try to edit your post to make it more concrete.

Comment: Agreed. What do you mean by "this doesnt work"? You dont receive the message? You dont receive the second part of the message? Your parsing logic fails? Something else?

Comment: I received a corrupted message, which made sense after reading selbie's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your first socket.Send call only sent 4 bytes:

```
socket.Send(dataWithHeader, 0, 4, SocketFlags.None);
```

That is, bytes at offsets of 0,1,2,and 3 get sent (4 bytes total). Remember the third parameter to socket.Send is a length parameter, not an ending position.

Thus, this line has a bug:

```
socket.Send(dataWithHeader, 5, dataWithHeader.Length - 5, SocketFlags.None);
```

It sends bytes from offset 5,6,7.. to the end of the array. **It skipped byte 4.**  Hence, the receiver likely blocks because it's one byte short of receiving a full message.

It should read:

```
socket.Send(dataWithHeader, 4, dataWithHeader.Length - 4, SocketFlags.None);
```

There you go.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to simulate a bad connection, in which 2 segments were sent one after the other

That's not a 'bad connection'. That's an entirely legal way for any TCP connection to behave. If the receiving software doesn't cope correctly with that it isn't written correctly.

> Assuming the first 4 bytes were sent fully

You can't assume that.